# How to open an Excel file with PHPExcel for both reading and writing?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using the PHPExcel library, and I'm creating xls objects either for writing or for reading:

`PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('file.xlsx')`
`PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter('Excel2007')`

How can I open an XLSX file for reading and writing?

Answer (score 59):

You load a file into PHPExcel using a reader and the load() method, then save that file using a writer and the save() method... but PHPExcel itself is unaware of the source of the PHPExcel object... it doesn't care whether you have loaded it from a file (or what type of file) or created it by hand.

As such, there is no concept of "opening for read/write". You simply read the file by name, and save to the same filename. That will overwrite the original file with any changes that you have made in your script.

**EDIT**

Example

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$fileType = 'Excel5';
$fileName = 'testFile.xls';

// Read the file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

// Change the file
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

// Write the file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($fileName);
```

And can I suggest that you read the documentation, and look at the sample code in /Tests

Comment: Could you write sample code to explain this? I don't understand when you speak of `using a reader and the load() method, then save that file using a writer and the save() method` you are talking about two different objects, (a reader, a writer) but I need to open the file, modify some cells and save that same object to a file.

Comment: this can cause a "Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted", can  be fixed?

Comment: It can probably be fixed be looking at the documented advice and recommendations for memory handling, such as using cell caching

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker.

Comment: Works perfectly!