# Edit XLSX in PHP

Tags: php, excel, xlsx

Hi there is a way to edit uploaded Excel (xlsx) document in PHP. Document is very simple (table with item names, price, quantity). I suppose PHPExcel able only read document but not edit? Any advices?

Comment: Why do you think PHPExcel will be unable to edit it? They have a `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007` class that seems to handle xlsx correctly.

Comment: Simply reading the PHPExcel site front page should have told you that it's read and write: phrases like "allow you to write to and read from" are the clue we give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PHPExcel to edit a document as well, check out these threads for more information:

- [Read - Edit - Write Excel File](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/261777)
- [PHPExcel modify existing .xlsx file with multiple worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594444/phpexcel-modify-existing-xlsx-file-with-multiple-worksheet)
- [How to open an Excel file with PHPExcel for both reading and writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797103/how-to-open-an-excel-file-with-phpexcel-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Comment: Oh thanks! Its can be confusing when using different documents for upload. I'll try to explain crealry. There is a system which generates excel documents (there is three templates with different layouts but generates same table in different style) so in provided examples the edited cells was chosen manualy ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
, So how to find out which field has the information, and after editing how to find out which cell was edited and save the changes?

Comment: @DeividasJuškevičius: You can look at official docs of PHPExcel or their support forum for more info actually.

Comment: PHPExcel is archived and no longer supported. Its predecessor PHPSpreadsheet is available however

Answer (score 2):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) can edit XLSX documents using the technique of templates.

It is a library pure PHP.

By the way, it can also edit DOCX, PPTX, ODT, ODS, ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach.
For Example, I want to edit/update the column(expiryDate) in the sheet (sheet1).

```
$localFilePath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Projects/abc.xlsx";

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly(["sheet1"]);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($localFilePath);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$column = NULL;
foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $index => $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // This loops through all cells,
    foreach($cellIterator as $subIndex => $cell) {
        $value = $cell->getValue();
        if($index == 1 && $value == "expiryDate"){
           $column = $subIndex;   
        }
        if((empty($value) || $value == "") && $column == $subIndex && $index != 1){
           $cell->setValue("2050-12-31 00:00:00");
        }
    }
}
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
$writer->save($localFilePath);
```