# PHPExcel search cell by value

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm wondering, how it's possible to help with such issue.
Let's say, I have an excel with such info in it (it could be much more info):

```
**Country**            **Currency**
Germany                 EUR    
USA                     USD    
Russia                  RUB
```

and I'm entering in input form "USA", and I want to see the result USD from excel. 
Is there some kind of function in PHP, which allows to search for a value in excel?

Or at least, if there existing such function, which returns in which cell (e.g. B2) such value exists?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to PHPExcel to do a search, but it's pretty straightforward to write something yourself based around the iterators.... take a look at `28iterator.php` in `/Examples`

```
$foundInCells = array();
$searchValue = 'USA';
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $ws = $worksheet->getTitle();
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if ($cell->getValue() == $searchValue) {
                $foundInCells[] = $ws . '!' . $cell->getCoordinate();
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($foundInCells);
```

Of course, if you're only wanting to search a specific column in a specific worksheet, you can simplify this a great deal, e.g. using `rangeToArray()` and then searching the array using standard PHP array functions.

Comment: Be aware that by comparing the cell value with the search value using '==', any cell containing the number 0 will match any search string. This is a known PHP behavior (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string) but maybe it's worth using '===' or a more elaborate comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As there a re many different Excel Formats (2003, 2010 quirks, ooxml, etc.) you will have to look for a third party library to read excel files.

Find some examples [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776124/edit-xlsx-in-php) or [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php).

*Edit: added a more current question.*

Comment: Yes, I've seen those posts. I was using PHPExcel, but i haven't found a solution there. I don't need to write something in excels, I have simple file, from which I need to search by my keyword phrase correct cell

Comment: If you access your data from PHP, you only access the "data". You do not have the functionalities that the Excel application itself provides (like searching, ordering, etc.). You will have to do that by yourself. (Foreach, or load all data from excel into an array and check for the key or something like that.)

Comment: I'm able to retrieve particular cell by using functions like getCell(B2), but still even using different loops i'm not able to make a proper search :(

Comment: You can just read the whole table into an array: $arr[getCell(B1)] = getCell(B2); And then check get your value with $arr["USA"]; ... (all pseudo code^^)